# Using Logparser.exe with .etl files - Cannot retrieve high resolution timestamp

Tags: logparser, etw

I'm using `logparser.exe` (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) to process a captured trace (in a `.etl` file). The output however is not proving the high resolution timestamp that I know is recorded in the `.etl` file.

The output is spitting out timestamps only up to the seconds (i.e. `2014-07-24 18:52:39`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered my own question:

Logparser.exe by default formats the timestamps to exclude the milliseconds / nanoseconds. You have two options to view a higher resolution timestamp:

#### 1. Verbosely convert your specific fields using `TO_STRING(Timestamp, 'HH:mm:ss.ln')`. An example useage is below:

> c:>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe" -i:ETW -o:CSV "SELECT TO_STRING(Timestamp, 'HH:mm:ss.ln') AS Timestamp, 
>    EventTypeName FROM 'c:\PerfLogs\ASP\LocalSystem\20140724-000003\Verbose Trace.etl'" > verbose.csv

#### 2. Change all timestamp output regardless of which field using the `-oTsFormat` argument:

> c:>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe" -i:ETW -o:CSV -oTsFormat "HH:mm:
>   ss.ln" "SELECT * FROM 'c:\PerfLogs\ASP\LocalSystem\20140724-000003\Verbose Trace.etl'" > verbose.csv

#### Time Format Strings:

*More time format strings are listed here: http://strivinglife.com/words/post/Microsoft-Log-Parser-timestamp-formats*

- HH - Hour
- mm - Minute
- ss - seconds
- l - milliseconds
- n - nanoseconds